# 404 status error in ajax response of asp .net mvc application after deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, http-status-code-404, web-deployment

"The page can not be found" error comes to response of ajax in asp .net mvc project after deployment. When I debug everything is fine, ajax works correctly The ajax function is below and works fine while debugging. The server is IIS6; is it about some permissions in sever or anything else?

In View:

```
@Html.Hidden("url_Prefix", Url.Action("SinavSonuc", "Sonuc"))
```

In Javascript:

```
var veri = { 'tcNo': $('input#tcNo').val(), 'evrakSayi': $('input#evrakSayi').val() };
var _url = $('input#url_Prefix').val();

$.ajax({
    url: _url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: veri,
    success: function (result) {
        ...
    },
    error: function (error, textstatus) {
        var errorAlert = JSON.stringify(error);
        alert(errorAlert);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The reason is "Verify that file exists" choice was checked in wildcard application map insertion of "C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" at iis6 deployment. I make "Verify that file exists" choice unchecked, and ajax works perfectly.